# Norms on $W^{1,p}(\Omega )$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. In different book, I have different norm for this space. The norms are the following one :

$$\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=\|u\|_{L^p}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}$$

$$\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=(\|u\|_{L^p}^p+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^p)^{1/p}$$

$$\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=\left(\|u\|_{L^p}^p+\sum_{i=1}^n\|\partial _i u\|_{L^p}^p\right)^{1/p}$$

$$\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=\|u\|_{L^p}+\sum_{i=1}^n\|\partial _i u\|_{L^p}.$$

Are they all equivalent ? And if yes, how can I show it ?

Comment: In short, yes (sort of). I believe Hölder gets the job done. Also note that $\partial_i u$ means the derivative of the i-th component of $u$ so the sums are just gradients.

Answer (score 1):

They are all equivalents. The equivalence of the two first norm and the two last is a common result. To have the equivalence of the first and the third, use the equivalence of norms of $\mathbb R^n$ as following :

$$\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^p=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^p,$$
where $|\nabla u|=:|\nabla u|_2=\sqrt{\partial _1u^2+...+\partial _n u^2}$. Since $|\cdot |_2$ is equivalent to $|\cdot |_p$, there are $C,D>0$ s.t. $$C|\nabla u|_p\leq |\nabla u|_2\leq D|\nabla u|_p$$
and thus $$C\sum_{i=1}^n\|\partial _i u\|_{L^p}^p\leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^p\leq D\sum_{i=1}^n\|\partial _i u\|_{L^p}^p,$$
and conclude.

The rest follow from all the previous results.